# how to copy PostgreSQL Streaming Replication File into some HDD drive every 5 minutes

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to `PostgreSQL`, what I know we can replicate data from one database/server to other.

[image]

My C# app continuously writing data to some database having only 1 table.

1. I need file based log shipping copy to some drive of my HDD rather than to some other database, can I do that?
2. Is data truncated from Master database once replication done?
3. I want every 5 minute replication and copy the log files.

Please suggest and help.

Comment: PostgreSQL has `archive_command`. You don't need to write an app for this.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html